# How to set all variables in function as local

Tags: functions, scoping, meta-programming

Here is an example code:

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = a + b;

f[x_, y_] := Module[{a = 3, b = 2, c}, c = (x + y)*(a + b)];
```

`a,b,c` are used outside of the function `f` and also inside `f`.

**How can I ensure that all used variables in a function are local WITHOUT specifing all of them in `Module[{local variables},...]`.** This can be extremely annoying when I use many variables.

Comment: Why not just create unique variables then?

Comment: @Feyre: I want to reuse some SAME variable names outside and inside the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is a duplicate but I can't find it. Here's something you may find useful:

```
myModule // ClearAll
myModule // Attributes = {HoldAll}
myModule[expr_] := Module[
    { spec = (
          Union[ Join @@ Cases[
              Hold[expr]
           ,  s_Symbol /; Context[Unevaluated[s]] === "Global`" :> Hold[s]
           , {-1}
           , Heads -> False
          ]]
      ) /. Hold[spec__] :> Hold[{spec}]
    }
  , Module @@ (Hold[Evaluate[Unevaluated @@ spec], expr])
]
```

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = a + b;

f[x_, y_] := myModule[a = 3; b = 2; c = (x + y)*(a + b)];
```

```
f[1, 2]
a
b
```

> 15
>
> 1
>
> 1

Short explanation

- `Cases` extracts all symbols from `` Global` `` context, could be *not* from `` System` `` but then Package symbols would be used too. I know `` Global` `` isn't always the `$Context` so maybe `$Context` would be better? Don't know, up to you.

  It ignores head so from `f[g,h]` only `g` and `h` will be extracted. Do you want that? Again, don't know, feel free to change it.

  At the end it returns `{Hold[g], Hold[h],...`
- then we transform this result to `Hold[{g,h,...}`
- `Module` assembling

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Perfect. But, I am not able to understand what the code is doing. Could you please shortly describe in words what you main idea was. Thank you.

Comment: @lio let me know if that is enough

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  This is a very important solution for all newbies who are coming from other languages to Mathematica. Am I really the first who is asking this question, I cannot believe it?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Modules and Local Variables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModulesAndLocalVariables.html), there is no other way of making variable literally local, than specifying it in the `Module` statement. You may consider declaring list as a local variable: `Module[{locVars={1, 3, 4}}...` and referring its elements or introduce an wolfram language package with its own private symbols: [Setting Up Wolfram Language Packages](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html).